# Getting "The argument type 'Widget?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'" error

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, consumer

I'm trying to build a **Consumer** but I'm getting this

> The argument type 'Widget?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.

error underlined on the child inside the **builder**.
Here's the code:

```
Consumer<Cart>(
        builder: (_, cart, ch) => Badge(
              child: ch,
              value: cart.itemCount.toString(),
            ),
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.shopping_cart,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
```

Here's the Badge item it refers to:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
    child,
    Positioned(
      right: 8,
      top: 8,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        // color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: 16,
          minHeight: 16,
        ),
        child: Text(
          value,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 10,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical builder function would look like this:

```dart
Consumer<FooModel>(
  builder: (context, model, child) {
    return Text(model.foo());
  }
)
```

However, if `builder` is very expensive, it may be possible to move some of it out of the builder, and into a `child` parameter:

```dart
Consumer<FooModel>(
  builder: (context, model, child) {
    return Column(children: [
      Text(model.foo()),
      VeryExpensiveWidget(),  // this gets rebuilt every time FooModel updates
    ])
  }
)
```

can become:

```dart
Consumer<FooModel>(
  builder: (context, model, child) {
    return Column(children: [
      Text(model.foo()),
      child,  // this gets passed into the builder function
    ])
  },
  child: VeryExpensiveWidget(),  // pass it as a child of the consumer
)
```

This effectively caches `VeryExpensiveWidget`, building it once and then using that for all future calls to the builder.

The problem is that you may not pass a `child` in. In the first example, we don't need the child parameter, and this is totally fine. However, it means that `child` is now `null`. Because this is allowed behaviour, `child` must be a `Widget?`

In your case, you always pass in a `child` parameter, so you can guarantee that the `child` passed into `builder` is non-null, so it is safe to use `child!` to forcibly convert `child` into a `Widget`

Your builder would then become:

```dart
builder: (_, cart, child) => Badge(child: child!, value: cart.itemCount.toString()),
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally the code for Consumer-Type 'Listener' for the created Provider would be like as below:

```
Consumer<CartDataProvider>(
            builder: (_, receivedCartDataProvider, fixedChildThatWeProvide) {
              return Badge(
                child: fixedChildThatWeProvide!,
                value: receivedCartDataProvider.cartItemCount.toString(),
                color: Colors.white,
              );
            },
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          )
```